# How to keep open file input in Visual Studio Code when I change of window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know if it is possible to keep this search engine (Ctrl-P) open if I change the window, in Visual Studio Code.

It is a not very relevant functionality but it would help me when I forget part of the name of the file I want to search for or I have to change the window to solve another situation, however, when returning to Visual Studio Code the file browser closed itself and I must return to write part of the file path from the start.

Is there a configuration or extension with this functionality?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot keep that open when you change windows. Since the search engine provides compilers or lints for various languages that you are editing in the ide space. So when you open a new window by default VS code provides a different configuration for the script, so the search engine cannot be kept open.

A detailed description can be found here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings